# HTML - Possible to fix table width?

Tags: html, html-table, width

Is it possible to make a table with lets say 4 columns with of 1 row with 100px in width, and then have to cells below with a with of 200px without having to create a new table?

Because if i do this, then when i set the width of 200px in new cells, the other cell changes width too.. i want the to new cells to expand to fill up the rest of the width left.

Here an example..

```
<table border="1" width="100%">
<tr>
<td width="100px">1</td>
<td width="100px">2</td>
<td width="100px">3</td>
<td width="100px">4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="200px">5</td>
<td width="200px">6</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Holy HTML 101, Batman. https://www.google.com/search?q=html+tables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## JsFiddle demo

you actally need to use `colspan`, so you code will be as below this will do the work you want

```
<table border="1" width="100%">
<tr>
<td width="100px">1</td>
<td width="100px">2</td>
<td width="100px">3</td>
<td width="100px">4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td  colspan="2">5</td>
<td colspan="2">6</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

`<td colspan="number">` -number Specifies the number of columns a cell should span. Note: colspan="0" tells the browser to span the cell to the last column of the column group (colgroup)

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the cell width from the second row, but add an additional attribute to each of them, so it reads like:

```
<td colspan="2"></td>
<td colspan="2"></td>
```

This should have both these cells account for 2 cells widths, without the need to redefine their widths.

[MDN TD - Attribute Colspan](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/td#attr-colspan)